# How to have a "goto" statement / How to establish a loop?

Tags: ruby

This is the portion of the code that is bothering me:

```
print "Command, please: "
command = gets.chomp
    case.response
    when 0
        exit
    when 1
        puts "Hello, world!"
```

I want the program to repeat back to the *print "Command, please:* " portion and allow me to type in another "command"  after the command has been completed (For example, after command 1, where I have commanded the program to say *"Hello, world!"*

Therefore, should I add a `goto` statement or something of the like? As far as I know, there is no `goto` function in Ruby. I tried to Google an alternative for the `goto` function in Ruby and I haven't gotten a straightforward, beginner-friendly answer.

Or should I create a loop beginning at *print "Command, please: "* and use the `redo` function after the commands? If so, how can I establish the loop? In other words, what do I type so that Ruby understands where I want the loop to begin?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
loop do # Edit: more Rubyesque than 'while true', see comments and other answers.
  print "Command, please: "
  command = gets.chomp
  case command
    when "0"
      exit
    when "1"
      puts "Hello, world!"
  end
end
```

Note:

`case command` - you're checking the command variable, not a `response` method on the case object.

`when "0"` - what comes back will always be a string, so it will never match `0` - an integer.

`end` - you've opened a case statement.

Comment: `loop do` instead of `while true`.

Comment: Yes, [Kernel#loop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) is more idomatic. Also, `loop` handles the exception `StopIteration` by breaking the loop, which is often convenient when using enumerators. If the enumerator `enum` is at the end of the enumeration, `e.next` and `e.peek` will raise a `StopIteration` exception.

Comment: I love S.O. comments more than the questions and answers. Answer updated.

Answer (score 4):

A loop it is. You can achieve what you're looking for by wrapping your code in a `loop` block like this

```
loop do
   # Your program
end
```

Comment: `loop`, eh? New one on me... :D

Comment: Ahmad, that's got to be the easiest 30-and-counting rep points you've ever earned! :-)